# Scale array values after resizing an image in python

Tags: python, arrays, resize, scale

I have a `480x640` image and I am cropping to `195x195`.
The original `480x640` has a corresponding `(68,2)` array which can be used to further process the image. Since I cropped the image, how am can I rescale the `(68,2)` array values to correspond to the new cropped image?

I tried to do something along the line:

```
shape = shape*((195*195)/(480*640))
```

but it was no use. N.B. `shape` is the `(68,2)` array